# Pandas left join returning multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, left-join

I am using python to merge two dataframe:

`join=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=["A","B"],how="left")`

Table 1:

```
         A   B
         a   1
         b   2
         c   3
```

Table 2:

```
         A   B  Flag   C
         a   1   0    20
         b   2   1    40 
         c   3   0    60
         a   1   1    80
         b   2   0    10
```

The result that I get after left join is:

```
         A   B  Flag  C
         a   1   0    20
         a   1   1    80
         b   2   1    40
         b   2   0    10  
         c   3   0    60
```

Here we see row 1 and row 2 has come twice because of table 2. I want to keep just one row based on `Flag` column. I want to keep one of the two rows whose `Falg` value is `= 1

So Final Expected output is:

```
          A   B  Flag  C
           a   1   1   80
           b   2   1   40
           c   3   0   60
```

Is there any pythonic way to do it?

Comment: You are not clear. You say for this example that "[in the join] I want to keep just one [...] of the two rows whose Flag value is = 1". But what is the general rule no matter what is in the tables? Do you mean, if a table 2 AB subrow appears with both 0 & 1 that you want to drop 0 row before joining? Even if there is no match in table 1? Can flag only be 0 or 1? Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
# raise preferred lines to the top
df2 = df2.sort_values(by='Flag', ascending=False) 

# deduplicate
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['A','B'],  keep='first')

# merge
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A','B'])

   A  B  Flag   C
0  a  1     1  80
1  b  2     1  40
2  c  3     0  60
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept is similar to what you would do on SQL: separate a table with the selection criterea (in this case maximums for flag), leaving enough columns to match an observation on the joint table.

```
join = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="left").reset_index()
maximums = join.groupby(by='A').max()
join = pd.merge(join, maximums, on=['Flag', 'A'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this join:

```
join=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=["A","B"],how="left", left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(join)
```